# AWS Application Load balancer - HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count vs HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count?

Tags: amazon-web-services

What is the actual difference between `HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count` and `HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count`?

Could understand that `HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count` is based on http code returned by ELB and `HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count` is based on http code returned by target. Still not able to understand how to analyze and troubleshoot the count for each metrics?

Is this count depended on health check failure?

Answer (score 6):

Based on the doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html

The answer above seems wrong, should be:

- HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count -  This is the number
  of 4XX errors that are returned from the ELB.
- HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count - This is simply a 4XX error returned from the
  application servers.

Comment: To go further, these counts are exclusive of each other, meaning a  400 returned from the application server will not be counted in the elb counts (HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count). This is noted in metric description from the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 metrics used to help diagnose where the fault lies for ay 4XX errors.

- `HTTPCode_ELB_4XX_Count` - This is simply a 4XX error returned from the application servers.
- `HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count` - This is the number of 4XX errors that are returned from the ELB.

To get a gauge of what can trigger this take a look at [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#load-balancer-http-error-codes) for a list of HTTP statuses mapped to the cause of the ELB error.

Comment: Did you mean this?
    HTTPCode_Target_4XX_Count - This is simply a 4XX error returned from the application servers.